# Slider stopped working, jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I need little help. I have a wordpress website http://galaxylanguagesolutions.com/ 
on homepage Partners logo slider is not rotating automatically and the previous & next links are also not working.. I inspected it in console, it is giving me error :

```
ReferenceError: create_jcarousel is not defined
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance : )

Comment: Click F12 and look at the line above the error - remove the second instance of jQuery `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://galaxylanguagesolutions.com/wp-content/themes/Translation/js/jquery.js'></script>` you only need the first

Comment: @mplungjan , Thank you for the comment sir, But that didn't worked.

Comment: It must have improved something. Look in the console again for other errors - perhaps you have MORE jQuery files included